# Python: Add tk menu elemts from other classses

Tags: python, class, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I made a GUI app which grew until getting similar to the `__init__` document of Tkinter, but the problem is all inside of one class. I'm trying to refactor the code in many different classes to later put in different files because now is complicated to read and understand the code. Also, tests will be more complicated and it's not good to follow the god class method.

I am not available to make work for the different classes. I try with a short version firstly. So following this code:

**■ How I can add the EditMenu to the main menu_bar?**

**■ How I can use functions from other classes on my main tk elements to edit it or anything?**

```
import tkinter as tk  

class MainApp(tk.Tk)

    file = None

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        
        self.wm_title("Test Application")
     
    # MENU:   
        menu_bar = tk.Menu(self)
        file_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=FilesOptions.open_file)
        file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=FilesOptions.save_file)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
    
    #CONTENT:
        text_area = Text(self)
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(text_area)
        
        text_area.grid(sticky = N + E + S + W)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
        scrollbar.config(command=self.text_area.yview)
        text_area.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
         
    # CONFIGURATION:
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1) 
    
    def set_title(self,name="Untitled"):
        self.title(name)
        
    
class FilesOptions:
    
    def open_file(): 
        MainApp.file = askopenfilename(defaultextension=".txt", 
                                    filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"), 
                                        ("Text Documents","*.txt")]) 
        if MainApp.file == "":   # no file to open 
            MainApp.file = None     
        else:       # Try to open the file
            MainApp.set_title(os.path.basename(MainApp.file)) 
            MainApp.text_area.delete(1.0,END) 
            file = open(MainApp.file,"r") 
            MainApp.text_area.insert(1.0,file.read()) 
            file.close()
            
    
    def save_file():
        MainApp.file = asksaveasfilename(initialfile='Untitled.txt', 
                                            defaultextension=".txt", 
                                            filetypes=[("All Files","*.*"), 
                                                ("Text Documents","*.txt")]) 
        if MainApp.file == "": 
            MainApp.file = None
        else:       # Try to save the file 
            file = open(MainApp.file,"w") 
            file.write(MainApp.text_area.get(1.0,END)) 
            file.close() 
            MainApp.set_title(os.path.basename(MainApp.file))
    
    
        
class EditMenu(tk.Menu):
    
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        self.add_command(label="speed filter",command=Effects.color)
        self.add_command(label="blur filter",command=Effects.blur)
        self.add_command(label="sharper filter", command=Effects.sharp)


class Effects():
    
    def color():
        pass

    def blur():
        pass
    
    def sharp():
        pass
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> How I can add the EditMenu to the main menu_bar?

Since `EditMenu` inherits from `Menu`, you do it the same way you add any other menu.

```
class MainApp(tk.Tk)
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        menu_bar = tk.Menu(self)
        ...
        edit_menu = EditMenu(menu_bar)
        menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
```

> How I can use functions from other classes on my main tk elements to edit it or anything?

The mistake you're making is you're calling methods on a class rather than on an instance of a class. That's fine if you define the methods as class methods, but you haven't done that.

I think a more common solution is to create an instance of the class, passing in the controller an an argument to `__init__`. Then, you call methods on the instance. These methods will  have access to the controller, and thus have access to any data managed by the controller.

```
class EditMenu(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.effects = Effects(controller)
        self.add_command(label="speed filter",command=self.effects.color)
        self.add_command(label="blur filter",command=self.effects.blur)
        self.add_command(label="sharper filter", command=self.effects.sharp)
```